Undefined references when linking Google Benchmark with g++ on Windows (MSYS2) using vcpkg
I'm trying to use Google Benchmark with the g++ compiler on Windows. I installed the library using the vcpkg package manager with the triplet x64-mingw-static.
Here is the command I used to install it:
vcpkg install benchmark:x64-mingw-static

I have verified that the files benchmark.a and benchmark_main.a exist in the specified directory. Here is the command:
g++ -std=c++23 test_benchmark.cpp -isystem "C:\\Program Files\\vcpkg\\installed\\x64-mingw-static\\include" -L "C:\\Program Files\\vcpkg\\installed\\x64-mingw-static\\lib" -lbenchmark -lbenchmark_main -lpthread -o benchmark_test.exe

This resulted in the following errors:
C:/Program Files/MSYS2/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\benji\AppData\Local\Temp\ccrIFsd8.o:test_benchmark:(.text+0x66): undefined reference to `__imp__ZN9benchmark5State16StartKeepRunningEv'
C:/Program Files/MSYS2/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\benji\AppData\Local\Temp\ccrIFsd8.o:test_benchmark:(.text+0xf4): undefined reference to `__imp__ZN9benchmark5State17FinishKeepRunningEv'
C:/Program Files/MSYS2/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\benji\AppData\Local\Temp\ccrIFsd8.o:test_benchmark:(.text+0x1a3): undefined reference to `__imp__ZN9benchmark5State16StartKeepRunningEv'
C:/Program Files/MSYS2/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\benji\AppData\Local\Temp\ccrIFsd8.o:test_benchmark:(.text+0x23b): undefined reference to `__imp__ZN9benchmark5State17FinishKeepRunningEv'
C:/Program Files/MSYS2/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\benji\AppData\Local\Temp\ccrIFsd8.o:test_benchmark:(.text+0x2ca): undefined reference to `__imp__ZN9benchmark16PrintDefaultHelpEv'
C:/Program Files/MSYS2/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\benji\AppData\Local\Temp\ccrIFsd8.o:test_benchmark:(.text+0x2df): undefined reference to `__imp__ZN9benchmark10InitializeEPiPPcPFvvE'
C:/Program Files/MSYS2/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\benji\AppData\Local\Temp\ccrIFsd8.o:test_benchmark:(.text+0x2f1): undefined reference to `__imp__ZN9benchmark27ReportUnrecognizedArgumentsEiPPc'
C:/Program Files/MSYS2/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\benji\AppData\Local\Temp\ccrIFsd8.o:test_benchmark:(.text+0x305): undefined reference to `__imp__ZN9benchmark22RunSpecifiedBenchmarksEv'
C:/Program Files/MSYS2/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\benji\AppData\Local\Temp\ccrIFsd8.o:test_benchmark:(.text+0x30e): undefined reference to `__imp__ZN9benchmark8ShutdownEv'
C:/Program Files/MSYS2/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\benji\AppData\Local\Temp\ccrIFsd8.o:test_benchmark:(.text+0x335): undefined reference to `__imp__ZN9benchmark8internal17InitializeStreamsEv'
C:/Program Files/MSYS2/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\benji\AppData\Local\Temp\ccrIFsd8.o:test_benchmark:(.text+0x398): undefined reference to `__imp__ZN9benchmark8internal25RegisterBenchmarkInternalEPNS0_9BenchmarkE'
C:/Program Files/MSYS2/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\benji\AppData\Local\Temp\ccrIFsd8.o:test_benchmark:(.text+0x409): undefined reference to `__imp__ZN9benchmark8internal25RegisterBenchmarkInternalEPNS0_9BenchmarkE'
C:/Program Files/MSYS2/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\benji\AppData\Local\Temp\ccrIFsd8.o:test_benchmark:(.text$_ZN9benchmark8internal17FunctionBenchmarkC1ERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEPFvRNS_5StateEE[_ZN9benchmark8internal17FunctionBenchmarkC1ERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEPFvRNS_5StateEE]+0x22): undefined reference to `__imp__ZN9benchmark8internal9BenchmarkC2ERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE'
C:/Program Files/MSYS2/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\benji\AppData\Local\Temp\ccrIFsd8.o:test_benchmark:(.text$_ZN9benchmark8internal17FunctionBenchmarkC1ERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEPFvRNS_5StateEE[_ZN9benchmark8internal17FunctionBenchmarkC1ERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEPFvRNS_5StateEE]+0x2b): undefined reference to `__imp__ZTVN9benchmark8internal17FunctionBenchmarkE'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

My cpp is:
#include <benchmark/benchmark.h>

static void BM_StringCreation(benchmark::State& state) {
    for (auto _ : state)
        std::string empty_string;
}
BENCHMARK(BM_StringCreation);

static void BM_StringCopy(benchmark::State& state) {
    std::string x = "hello";
    for (auto _ : state)
        std::string copy(x);
}
BENCHMARK(BM_StringCopy);

BENCHMARK_MAIN();

I've ensured that the vcpkg installation is integrated with my environment and that the include paths are correct. I'm currently using g++ from the MSYS2 distribution.
Can anyone help me figure out why the linker can't find the libraries and how to properly link Google Benchmark with g++ on Windows?

You shouldn't have to guess compiler flags, pkgconf --libs --cflags benchmark should print the correct flags (but you might need to set PKG_CONFIG_PATH to the pkgconfig directory of vcpkg) (or just install the library from msys2, which will put it into the default search path).

Main problem is that you are building this manually. You should use cmake (and configure it with favorite generator) or something similar, so it would take over build process.

If you want to link with the static benchmark libraries you must define BENCHMARK_STATIC_DEFINE before the benchmark's include.
#define BENCHMARK_STATIC_DEFINE
#include <benchmark/benchmark.h>

// Your benchmark code goes here

Or define in to the compiler
g++ -std=c++23 test_benchmark.cpp -DBENCHMARK_STATIC_DEFINE -isystem "C:\\Program Files\\vcpkg\\installed\\x64-mingw-static\\include" -L "C:\\Program Files\\vcpkg\\installed\\x64-mingw-static\\lib" -lbenchmark -lbenchmark_main -lpthread -o benchmark_test.exe


Thank you for helping me resolve Google Benchmark compilation issues. If it helps someone else, I added -lshlwapi to the g++ arguments for WinAPI support, and it worked for me. Here’s the final command:
g++ -std=c++23 test_benchmark.cpp -DBENCHMARK_STATIC_DEFINE -isystem "C:\Program Files\vcpkg\installed\x64-mingw-static\include" -L "C:\Program Files\vcpkg\installed\x64-mingw-static\lib" -lbenchmark -lbenchmark_main -lshlwapi -lpthread -o benchmark_test.exe

Quite unfortunately the only way I was able to make it compile is to use cmake ...
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)

project(MyBenchmarkProject LANGUAGES CXX)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 23)

set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Release)

if(MSVC)
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE "/O2 /DNDEBUG")
else()
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE "-O3 -DNDEBUG -march=native -flto -funroll-loops -fstrict-aliasing -fno-plt")
endif()

find_package(benchmark REQUIRED)

add_executable(MyBenchmark ex.cpp)

target_link_libraries(MyBenchmark PRIVATE benchmark::benchmark benchmark::benchmark_main)

if(WIN32)
  target_link_libraries(MyBenchmark PRIVATE pthread)
endif()


